# scala class with injecting constructer along with explicit passing parameter

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, akka

I have an actor class that takes takes arguments when propping the actor:

```
class UserSocket(uid:String,out:ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  //some code
}
```

I will call the `props` as:

```
def props(user: String)(out: ActorRef) = {
  Props(new UserSocket(user, out))
}
```

Now I need to inject reactivemongo to `UserSocket` actor, I have tried `current.injector` but it's deprecated.

Comment: Guice's assisted inject (provided you're using runtime DI) is probably the way to go here.

Comment: See this page at the docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka#Dependency-injecting-actors

Comment: thanks for reply @rethab, I am unable understand Guice's Assisted inject and I can't find any example that related to my problem in scala

Comment: I have created a module and Factory trait in UserSocket Object, Now how could I call Props ?